# Pyside6 GUI crashes when updating GUI after threading

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, qthread, pyside6

So basically the title, after threading I try to update the GUI, but it stops responding and closes. I am using qt designer so the GUI itself is in another file. The first code block is where I make the GUI interactive. The second is what will be run in the thread. I really appreciate any help you can provide.

```
class interact(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
def __init__(self):
super(interact, self).__init__()
self.setupUi(self)
self.scaleX = 800
self.scaleY = 800
self.index = 0
self.newIndex = 0
self.translatedFiles = \[\]
self.files = \[\]
self.isClicked = False
self.upload.clicked.connect(self.upload1)
self.upload.clicked.connect(self.change1)
self.rightArrow.clicked.connect(self.moveRight)
self.leftArrow.clicked.connect(self.moveLeft)
self.translate.clicked.connect(self.translate1)
self.translate.clicked.connect(self.change)

    def upload1(self):
        filenames, _ =  QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(
            None,
            "QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames()",
            "",
            "Image files (*.jpg *.png)"
        )
        for file in filenames:
            self.files.append(file)
        self.showImage()
    
    def moveRight(self):
        if self.isClicked == True:
            if self.newIndex >= len(self.translatedFiles)-1:
                self.newIndex = len(self.translatedFiles)-1
            else:
                self.newIndex += 1
        else:
            if self.index >= len(self.files)-1:
                self.index = len(self.files)-1
            else:
                self.index += 1
        self.showImage()
        
    def moveLeft(self):
        if self.isClicked == True:
            if self.newIndex <= 0:
                self.newIndex = 0
            else:
                self.newIndex -= 1
        else:
            if self.index <= 0:
                self.index = 0
            else:
                self.index -= 1
        self.showImage()
    
    def showImage(self):
        #actual = QImage(self.files[self.index])
        if self.isClicked == True:
            im = self.translatedFiles[self.newIndex]
            im = im.convert("RGB")
            data = im.tobytes("raw","RGB")
            qim = QImage(data, im.size[0], im.size[1], QImage.Format_RGB888)
            pix = QPixmap(qim)
            self.Image.setPixmap(pix)
            print("change")
        else:
            pix = QPixmap(self.files[self.index])
            self.Image.setPixmap(pix)
            print(self.files[self.index])
            print("KC")
    
    def afterThread(self, s):
        myarray = np.array(s)
        img = im.fromarray(myarray)
        self.translatedFiles.append(img)
        print("THREAD COMPLETE!")
        
        
    def change(self):
        self.isClicked = True
    
    def change1(self):
        self.isClicked = False
    
    def translate1(self):
        self.thread = QThread()
        self.worker = Translate(self.files[self.index])
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)
        self.thread.started.connect(self.worker.run)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.afterThread)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.thread.quit)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.worker.deleteLater)
        self.thread.finished.connect(self.thread.deleteLater)
        self.thread.finished.connect(self.showImage)
        self.thread.start()
```

Thread

```
class Translate(QObject):
    
    finished = Signal(list)
    def __init__(self, img):
        super(Translate, self).__init__()
        self.img1 = cv2.imread(img)
        self.image = cv2.cvtColor(self.img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        self.mocr = MangaOcr()
        # self.run()

    def chronos(func):
        def get_time(*args, **kawrgs):
            start = time.time()
            x = func(*args, **kawrgs)
            end = time.time()
            print("{} took {} seconds".format(func, (end-start)))
            return x
        return get_time

    @chronos
    def get_text(self, image):
        reader = easyocr.Reader(['ja'], gpu=False) 
        result = reader.readtext(image, paragraph=True)
        myDict = {}
        for (bbox, text) in result: 
            (tl, tr, br, bl) = bbox
            tl = (int(tl[0]), int(tl[1]))
            tr = (int(tr[0]), int(tr[1]))
            br = (int(br[0]), int(br[1]))
            bl = (int(bl[0]), int(bl[1]))
            myDict[str(bl)] = ([tl , br ])
        return myDict
    
    @chronos
    def get_japanese(self, diction):
        newList = {}
        et = {}
        ts = {}
        directory = os.getcwd()+'\MangaTranslation\cropText'
        for x in diction:
            cropped_image = self.image[diction[x][0][1]:diction[x][1][1], diction[x][0][0]:diction[x][1][0]]
            if not(os.path.exists(os.path.join(directory, str(x)+'.jpg'))):
                cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(directory, str(x)+'.jpg'), cropped_image)
            et[str(x)] = os.path.join(directory, str(x)+'.jpg')
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
            for x in files:
                try:
                    img = Image.open((root+"\\"+ x).strip())
                    text = self.mocr(img)
                    ts[(root+"\\"+ x).strip()] = text
                except:
                    print("not pic")
        mg = et.items()
        tg = ts.items()
        for coor, direct in mg:
            for dir1, jap in tg:
                if direct == dir1:
                    newList[coor] = jap
        return newList
    
    @chronos
    def translate(self, original):
        for jap in original:
            original[jap] = str(ts.bing(original[jap]))
        return original

    def segment(self, list1):
        for line in list1:
            newL= list(str(list1[line]))
            s = ''
            count = 0
            for x in range(len(newL)):
                    if newL[x] == " ":
                        count += 1
                    if count == 3:
                        newL[x] = "\n"
                        count = 0
                    s += newL[x]
            list1[line] = s
        return list1

    def write(self, img, dict1, list1):
        fontSize = .5
        # if img.shape > (1200, 851, 3):
        #     fontSize *= 10
        for value in dict1:
            cv2.rectangle(img, dict1[value][0], dict1[value][1], (0, 255, 255), 2)
            image = add_text_to_image(
                img,
                list1[value],
                font_color_rgb=(255, 0, 0),
                top_left_xy=(dict1[value][0][0], dict1[value][1][1]),
                font_scale= fontSize,
                font_face=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX
                )
        return image
        # plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (16,16)
        # plt.imshow(image)
        # plt.show()
    def run(self):
        gotten_text = self.get_text(self.image)
        finalText = self.get_japanese(gotten_text)
        newList = self.translate(finalText)
        addNewLine = self.segment(newList)
        final = self.write(self.image, gotten_text, addNewLine)
        self.finished.emit(final)
```

I have tried many things, but I get the same results.

Comment: Since we don't have the files you're using, we are not really able to test your code. Consider to provide a valid [mre] (by reducing the code to an example that reproduces the issue, what it actually does is irrelevant). Also, try to run the program from a terminal or prompt so that you can get a more comprehensive traceback.

Comment: I have the minimal code here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74330042/pyqt-gui-works-for-some-inputs-images-but-not-others