# stride issue turning numpy array into PIL Image and then into Qt QImage/QPixmap

Tags: python, numpy, qt, pyqt5, python-imaging-library

When I run the program it works for an image like https://pbs.twimg.com/media/FgbAe3UVEAEX_2l?format=jpg&name=large, but not for an image like https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Fdv8l_ZVEAIwLAk?format=jpg&name=medium. I have tried running it through the terminal, but I don't get any error, but the GUI stops responding and closes when I try the program with the second image. Any help would really be appreciated.

`minimal.py` (GUI):

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(457, 353)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.display = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.display.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 20, 271, 261))
        self.display.setScaledContents(True)
        self.display.setObjectName("display")
        self.upload = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.upload.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 300, 71, 21))
        self.upload.setObjectName("upload")
        self.translate = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.translate.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 300, 71, 21))
        self.translate.setObjectName("translate")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.display.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.upload.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "upload"))
        self.translate.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "modify"))
```

`main.py`:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QImage
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal
from minimal import Ui_MainWindow
from cvPic import Edit
class Interaction(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Interaction, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.index = 0
        self.newIndex = 0
        self.translatedFiles = []
        self.files = []
        self.isClicked = False
        self.upload.clicked.connect(self.upload1)
        self.upload.clicked.connect(self.change1)
        self.translate.clicked.connect(self.translate1)
        self.translate.clicked.connect(self.change)

    def showImage(self):
        if self.isClicked == True:
            im = self.translatedFiles[self.newIndex]
            qim = QImage(im[0], im[1].size[0], im[1].size[1], QImage.Format_RGB888)
            pix = QPixmap(qim)
            self.display.setPixmap(pix)
        else:
            pix = QPixmap(self.files[self.index])
            self.display.setPixmap(pix)
            print(self.files[self.index])

    def upload1(self):
        filenames, _ =  QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(
            None,
            "QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames()",
            "",
            "Image files (*.jpg *.png)"
        )
        for file in filenames:
            self.files.append(file)
        self.showImage()
    
    def change(self):
        self.isClicked = True

    def change1(self):
        self.isClicked = False

    def afterThread(self, s):
        self.translatedFiles.append(s)
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, self.showImage)
        print("THREAD COMPLETE!")

    def translate1(self):
        self.thread = QThread()
        self.worker = Edit(self.files[self.index])
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)
        self.thread.started.connect(self.worker.run)
        self.worker.result.connect(self.afterThread)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.worker.deleteLater)
        self.thread.finished.connect(self.thread.deleteLater)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.thread.quit)
        self.thread.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Interaction()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

`cvPic.py`:

```
import cv2
from PIL import Image
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, QRunnable, pyqtSignal, QObject, QThread
import numpy as np

class Edit(QObject):
    result = pyqtSignal(object)
    finished = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, img):
        super(Edit, self).__init__()
        self.img1 = cv2.imread(img)
        self.image = cv2.cvtColor(self.img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    def mod(self, img):
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5),cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)
        cv2.rectangle(blur, (0, 0), (250, 250), (0, 255,0), thickness=cv2.FILLED)
        cv2.line(blur, (0, 0), (250, 250), (255, 255,0), thickness=3)
        cv2.putText(blur, "HELLO WORLD!", (225, 225), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_TRIPLEX, 1.0, (255, 255, 255), 2)
        myarray = np.array(blur)
        img = Image.fromarray(myarray)
        im = img.convert("RGB")
        data = im.tobytes("raw","RGB")
        self.result.emit((data, im))
        self.finished.emit()
    
    def run(self):
        self.mod(self.image)
```

Comment: [mre] contains the word "minimal". what's the probability that I can delete a random line from your code and it still (mis)behaves in the same way? I see plenty of irrelevant stuff. you must determine if OpenCV is **absolutely required** to make this fail. if not, remove the tag.

Comment: OpenCV is absolutely required, the error only happens after I use OpenCV to modify the image and try to display it in the GUI.

Comment: no error, huh? does the script just end and return you to the shell prompt? what if you remove all the Qt stuff instead? determine if Qt is required to cause the issue.

Comment: Yeah, the script ends and returns to the shell. Without Qt it works fine, the script only ends when I try to incorporate the Edit class into Qt.

Comment: I figured out the file names of your three code blocks. this is more work than you should expect of anyone. -- when I run this, it works. it takes a moment to run, and it takes a moment to do the "modify". I get no issues at all, besides Qt showing the picture with some shearing, which is common in the mismatch between Qt and numpy arrays (you have grayscale data but claim it's RGB...). voting to close, not reproducible. -- "upload" is a file transfer to an internet server. this here isn't "upload". this is just "load"ing a picture file into a running program.

Comment: Yeah, I should have clarified. cvPic is the file name for the thread/edit class, the first block is a .ui file converted to .py. It is the file that has the buttons, PyQt window, etc. The second block is where I "merge" the first and third block(the cvPic file).

Comment: the issue is in your conversion from a numpy array to a QImage/QPixmap. the numpy arrays produced by OpenCV may use strides, so the QImage creation needs to take that into account, instead of just working with the shape directly. investigate that. people had this issue before you. -- a MRE would contain just ONE line of code in `mod()`, either an `imread()` or a `np.zeros(...)`. those suffice to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: you're mixing between numpy arrays and PIL Images more than I thought... the `showImage` method is a complete mess. you are throwing both a bytes object and a PIL object around, needlessly.

Comment: Ohh, I figured it had something to do with the images. Do you have any advice on how to properly process the image?